# Is there a way of combining Ogre3d's Hikari and BlazeDS?

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat, blazeds, ogre3d

I am trying to load a swf into an Ogre3d/Hikari application and that swf uses BlazeDS to communicate with a Tomcat server.  The swf is from another project that is used in a browser environment.  So, the swf is served from Tomcat to the client's browswer.  It seems like there are two main issues.  The first is a sandbox issue with using the swf in a different sandbox type than a browser environment.  The other issue seems to be setting up the BlazeDS message broker and the other communication channels and endpoints.
As far as both of the issues are concerned, it seems like the Hikari application is similar to an Adobe Air application and can use similar approaches.
Does this seem like a reasonable approach?  Does anybody have any similar experiences?  If so, how were things configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried what you want, but for the endpoints I suggest to use the same approach as in AIR (instead of using variables like {server} use hard coded endpoints).